# google spanner singleton reconnect on fault

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am creating a SpannerSingleton to stay connected for the duration of the app's life.
I'm interested in connection durability... if there is a session/connection issue how can I recreate a session?

One idea was to spawn a new connection increasing the setMaxSessions to a higher number if more than 90% of the pool is exhausted.  Like the opposite of exponential backoff? But where / how can I do that?  I could not find anything in the client library that would let me monitor the pool status or client count.

I went with [bill-pugh-singleton](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples#bill-pugh-singleton) cuz it seemed like a good choice...

Here is what I have:

```
public class SpannerSingleton {

    private static Spanner spanner;
    private static SpannerOptions options;

    private static SessionPoolOptions sessionPoolOps = SessionPoolOptions
            .newBuilder()
            .setMaxSessions(1000)  // 1000 concurrent queries
            .setMinSessions(100)  // keep 100 alive
            .setMaxIdleSessions(100)  // how many to keep from being idle and closed
            .build(); 

    private SpannerSingleton() {
        try {
            options = SpannerOptions
                    .newBuilder()
                    .setSessionPoolOption(sessionPoolOps)
                    .build();

            spanner = options.getService();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class SingletonHelper{
        private static final Spanner CONNECTION = new SpannerSingleton().spanner;
    } 

    public static synchronized Spanner getSpanner() {
        return SingletonHelper.CONNECTION;
    }

}
```

I use a Factory pattern to make the dbClient

```
public SpannerFactory {

    private static Spanner spanner = SpannerSingleton.getSpanner();
    private static DatabaseId dbId;

    public static DatabaseClient getConnection(String instance) {
        if (Util.isEmpty(instance)) return null;

        if ("mickey".equalsIgnoreCase(instance)) {
            dbId = DatabaseId.of(spanner.getOptions().getProjectId(), "instance1", "mickey");
        }

        if ("mouse".equalsIgnoreCase(instance)) {
            dbId = DatabaseId.of(spanner.getOptions().getProjectId(), "instance1", "mouse");
        }

        return spanner.getDatabaseClient(dbId);

    }
}
```

What I would like to add is something that would check for the connection pool to see how close to starved we are and then recreate itself... I might be over thinking it, but what might happen if the connection is disrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client library should take care of maintaining healthy session pool, user shouldn't have to worry about **sessions/connections** explicitly.

As documented in java client, if you set `MaxSessions` correctly - client will take care of maintaining those many sessions.

At a high level, the flow would be like:

```
If currentSessions < MaxSessions {
   if !idleSessions.empty()
        use an idle session.
   else
        CreateNewSession.
} else {
   Block/Fail based on action chosen in : ActionOnExhaustion.
}
```

If you want to avoid small overhead in **CreateSession** as part of request processing, one recommended option is to keep `minSessions` and `maxSessions` same as your concurrent **TPS** requirement so that at the beginning we have those many sessions ready to use.

For additional details like session monitoring, keeping idle sessions alive : please refer to documentation at : https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions